# Django REST Framework join table results in attribute exception

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am building an API in Django using REST Framework but am running into an issue.

Serializers:

```
class SquadSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Squad
        fields = ('name')

    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'})

class MembershipSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Membership
        fields = ('employee_id', 'squad_id')

    squad = SquadSerializer()
    employee = EmployeeSerializer()

class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    habitat = HabitatSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'function',
                'start_date', 'end_date', 'visible_site', 'habitat')
```

Models:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    function = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    visible_site = models.BooleanField()
    habitat = models.ForeignKey(Habitat, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

class Squad(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=40)

class Membership(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('employee', 'squad'))

    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=True, default=1)
    squad = models.ForeignKey(Squad, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=True, default=1)
```

The problem is that I keep running into this error:

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `name` on serializer `SquadSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Membership` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Membership' object has no attribute 'name'.
```

When executing this test (and a couple others)

```
def test_membership_serializer_id_name_field_content(self):
    """
    The name field of a squad should contain an id
    """
    serializer = create_membership_serializer(self.membership, '')
    self.assertEqual(serializer.data['id'], self.membership.id)
```

I've seen multipe people with the same issues here on Stack Overflow but the often suggest solution (to add many=True to SquadSerializer() and EmployeeSerializer()) doesn't work. I hope anyone here has any knowledge on why this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to map your seriailizer to your model, you should use `ModelSerializer`. In tupple, if it has only one value, you should write it as `(1,)` not `(1)`. Your `SquadSerializer` should be like

```
class SquadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Squad
        fields = ('name',) # or ('id', 'name')

    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'})
```

Your `MembershipSerializer` should be like

```
class MembershipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Membership
        fields = ('employee', 'squad')

    squad = SquadSerializer()
    employee = EmployeeSerializer()
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips, it doesn't appear to fix the issue though.

Comment: It seems that you are passing instance of `Squad` to `MembershipSerializer`.